# Generic OrderBy method

Tags: c#, sqlite, generics

I am trying to create a generic method to get the latest item ordered by a date property. Something like the following:

```
public async Task<DateTime> GetLatestModifiedDateAsync<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var result = await db.Table<T>()
                             .OrderByDescending(e => e.OrderedProperty)
                             .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return result.ModifiedAt;
    }
```

This obviously does not work because the property `OrderedProperty` cannot be found on the generic type, but how can I go about to get this working?

Comment: By giving `e => e.OrderProp` as a parameter. Read [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're sure that all your T has `OrderedProperty` property, just create an interface

```
interface IHaveOrderedProperty
{
    int OrderedProperty { get ; } 
}
```

and force `T` as `IHaveOrderedProperty`

```
public async Task<DateTime> GetLatestModifiedDateAsync<T>() 
      where T : IHaveOrderedProperty, new()
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work except for an issue inside of SQLite-net. Inside the AddOrderBy method I get a NotSupportedException. because the Lambda is as follow: e => Convert(e).ModifiedAt. This is because they don't support the Convert and only accept ExpressionType.Parameter.